# Halogen and inductive effect

Tags: aromatic-compounds, resonance, halides

background :

> As proved by rate of EAS, mesomeric or simply conjugated resonance is weaker for halogens than inductive and make them electron taking, with fluorine almost doing nothing due to strongest mesomeric and strongest inductive among halogens, So, halogens should take electrons away from any system if they do it in a specially conjugated system known for many resonating structures

[image]

If we have simple carbocation as shown in the chlorine and carbocation, being right next to chlorine Inductive effect must overpower resonance/mesomeric but why the opposite happens?

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, the energy costs for a sextet carbocation are too high to allow chlorine's strong inductive effects to dominate the situation.

The driving for for a carbon octet is very high.

Answer (score 1):

> If we have a simple carbocation as shown in the chlorine and carbocation example, being right next to chlorine the inductive effect should overpower resonance/mesomeric but why does the opposite happen?

No, it shouldn’t. Remember that chlorine’s electronegativity — a measure for the strength of its inductive effect — is *less* than both oxygen’s and nitrogen’s. Therefore, the inductive effect is *weakest for chlorine.*

All things considered, resonance effects usually overpower inductive effects, especially at short distances.

Comment: I'm with you on the weak inductive effect, but if you look at the inductive effect order, halogens beat NH2 and OH by a good margin, and 3p being so bad for resonance and having empty d orbital, back bonding strength is quite bad

Comment: Aren't inductive effects supposed to fade out quickly with distance and mesomeric or conjugative effect remains constant? if we look at a lot of problems, almost in everyone , inductive effect wins over mesomeric FCOOH (pKa=1)

Comment: @ELiT Stop any discussion with d-orbitals immediately. Main group elements’ d-orbitals are too far removed to take part in bonding. Yes, inductive effects are only relevant at short distances, but where mesomeric effects are helpful, they generally win. Note that in your carbonic acid fluoride example, the mesomeric effects are not helpful, so we have to consider inductive effects.

Comment: In EAS, oxygen and nitrogen are both activating substituents (i.e. their resonance effect wins out over their inductive effect). Chlorine, however, is weakly deactivating. Chlorine, having a lower electronegativity than oxygen, should be activating if all resonance factors are equal. This suggests that chlorine's poor overlap with the aromatic LUMO causes such poor resonance to occur that its lower inductive effect still dominates. Perhaps the increased electronegativity of the carbocation reduces the chlorine's inductive effect, rather than forming a π bond?

Comment: @DGS At least I can fully agree with the aromatic discussion: chlorine is bad at overlapping with $\ce{C=C}$ double bonds in general. I think that could be the reason why the extremely weak inductive effect actually plays a role. While if there is an empty p-orbital next to chlorine, it doesn’t have to interact with a pi-bond making the entire thing easier.

Comment: i couldn't really understand what you meant by "helpful" exactly how do we decide what's helpful? making it more acidic would make it unstable,no? if you're saying that the deprotonated form would be more stable then para halo aniline is less basic than aniline and there are lots of examples where inductive wins over mesomeric and the only example that i could find is the carbocation one

Comment: In most scales I'm accustomed to using, Chlorine has a higher electronegativity than nitrogen.

Comment: @Lighthart $\ce{NCl3}$ reacts with $\ce{HCl}$ to form $\ce{Cl2}$ — an experimental result clearly indicating that chlorine must have the partial positive charge in $\ce{NCl3}$.

Comment: @ELiT Helpful is a bad word choice, yeah. Maybe *productive* instead? In any case, the mesomeric effect of fluorine in $\ce{FCOOH}$ does little to deactivate the $\ce{OH}$ group’s acidity no matter which way you draw it.

Comment: https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/trans-3-Chloroacrylic_acid#section=Top ... sadly doesn't have pka, field effects would also be present but minimal in trans

Comment: @Jan all that means is that NCl2 has more electronegativivty than Cl, not Cl has less electronegativity than N.